# Is there any issues with storing a timeout as a property on a function?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any issues with storing a timeout as a property on a function?

```
/**
 * Show HTML Element for a brief period of time
 * @param {Object} element element to show
 * @param {Boolean} timeout show for a specific time
 * @param {Number} duration how long to show message
 **/
function showElement(element, timeout = true, duration = 3000) {
  element.style.display = "block";

  if (timeout) {
    
    if (showElement.elementTimeout != null) {
      clearTimeout(showElement.elementTimeout);
      showElement.elementTimeout = null;
    }

    showIcon.elementTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      element.style.display = "none";
    }, duration);
  }
}
```

More information:
The function is part of a set of utilities and functions.

Comment: It's quite odd to do, and there are better approaches, but there's nothing *inherently* incorrect about it

Comment: This will only allow you to have one timeout at a time in total. Whether that's an issue or not depends on how you intend to use the function.

Comment: @VLAZ the issue is that if i define a timeout inside a function it would or could be garbage collected before full duration.

Comment: Not if there is a reference to it. However, to provide a reference after the function ends you'd need to return some value or something. Again, depends on how you intend to use this.

Answer (score 0):

"Any issues" is a difficult question to answer. It does work but it's possible there could be unintended issues somewhere down the line.

```
let timeThing = {}

    timeThing.timer = (time) => setTimeout(() => console.log('I arrived'), time);

    timeThing.timer(5_000);
```

This will log 'I arrived' 5 seconds after being called but your other code will not wait for it to finally be called. You may want to clarify what issues you are worried about for a better answer. Also, as a side note, it would be referred to as a method instead of a property.